# Any authoritative references on nutrition?

Tags: nutrition

This year my wife any I dedicated the year to really getting in shape. Nutrition has become a significant topic in our lives and we're struggling to find a decent resource of nutritional information. For the most part, our diets have been developed through discovery. As our interest and focus is around Nutrition, it seems there is no end to the self help books on Dieting. When I go to Amazon or B&N, I can't seem to find a decent book on nutrition without finding some quacks way to eat like crap and still be fit.

Does anyone know of some good books on the science of nutrition, more the facts and less the religion.

Thanks ahead of time all!

Comment: Questions about Nutrition are off topic according to the [help/on-topic]. You might be interested in the [Nutrition](http://goo.gl/Gvc3BY) proposal on Area51, though.

Comment: http://www.midtown.com/blog/271/would-nutritional-information-on-menus-change-your-choices#.UoH5F-JMfIU could be good reference and if u looking to buy any product then i would recommended.
hellalife.com

Answer (score 3):

Probably one of your best options is to go to your local college, or hit up Amazon/eBay for a nutrition textbook, preferably one that has an edition that has been printed in the last year or two. As nutrition is an advancing field, anything older than 3+ years is likely to have some outdated information.

As far as the diet books in the local bookstore, your best choices will be the ones labeled pretty blandly, and are not of a particular diet (Such as Paleo, South Beach, Atkins, etc.) While these diets may have some validity, many of them are primarily created/written solely for the purpose of selling more information on the created plan.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not sure how the site is on nutrition as a whole, examine.com does an amazing job with supplements. Thorough research, clear explanations and they seem to have all of them covered. I would check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can find plenty of online resources, though some of them might actually be disguised ads. Here is one example resource -

http://www.muscleandfitness.com/news-and-features/galleries/nutrition/12-laws-fat-burning

Really if you adopt and stick to few basic laws of nutrition you will start seeing results. You do not need to know nutrition in too much detail as that itself is an extensive field, you risk getting lost in all the jargon and calorie counts. Just knowing the basics and learning a few healthy recipes will serve your goal. That is my experience.